# Project world map to Esri EPSG in GeoServer

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver

What I would like to do is to project world map from EPSG:4326 to other ones in GeoServer, special for the Esri EPSG world projection methods. GeoServer has so many EPSG codes in the demo/srslist, but seems most of them do not work.

For example,from EPSG 4326 to 54052 PROJCRS["World_Goode_Homolosine_Land"], I put the gt-epsg-extension-23.2.jar which mainly support the Esri EPSGs to the GeoServer lib path，it should have done for it's projection, but nothing happens.

So how to make GeoServer support the Esri world map projection, like "World_Goode_Homolosine_Land" 54052, "World_Bonne" 54024 or "World_Winkel" 54019? GeoTools maybe supported the Esri EPSGs, does some errors happen in the GeoServer inside?

Comment: Please do not delete and repost questions; doing so can cause automated defense mechanisms to engage.

Comment: The underlying library that implements the map projection algorithms must support the deifnitions too.

Comment: You can't have an Esri EPSG, you can have Esri defined coordinate reference systems, and EPSG defined coordinate reference systems.